# Javascript in HTML not executing over SSL connection

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, jenkins

I'm serving the following HTML via Jenkins https with an invalid security certificate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">alert(1);</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">alert(2);</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">alert(3);</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If I view source on the page in the browser, this is what I see.  However, I do not get the alerts.

If I open the page as a local file `file://.../index.html` I get the popups.  This happens on multiple browsers and multiple clients.

If I open the javascript console and type `alert(1);` I do not get the alert, but I do get `undefined` which means it ran the function and it didn't return anything.

Why is this?

Comment: As to the console, it returns `undefined` because that's what functions return in JavaScript when they don't have an explicitly specified return value. So of course `alert()` is going to return `undefined`, what else would it?

Comment: Right, but I don't get the alert, that's what I should have said

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome and IE, seems to be okay for me (http://imgur.com/a/iPKgk). I imagine it might have something to do with your PC security such as AV/firewall

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a Jenkins thing, running this in the scripting console fixed my issue:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';")
```

Here is a link to the documentation about the "Content Security Policy" header that pointed us in the right direction:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy